# Autocmd ignores mapping?

Tags: vim, vimrc

For convenience I mapped "unindenting" to SHIFT+TAB in my .vimrc:

```
nnoremap <S-Tab> <<
inoremap <S-Tab> <C-D>
```

This works fine if I use it myself while editing, and so I wanted to use that mapping for `autocmd` as well:

```
autocmd FileType html inoremap ;p <p><Enter><Tab>INDENTED<Enter><S-Tab></p>
```

This wont work though. I now use `<C-D>` directly:

```
autocmd FileType html inoremap ;p <p><Enter><Tab>INDENTED<Enter><C-D></p>
```

which works fine and is even shorter, so no problem.

---

This is thus more a question out of curiosity why autocmd can not use my mapping although it is in the right mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the `autocmd` is not relevant to the issue.

You're using the "nore" variant of map commands, which explicitly tells Vim not to trigger other mappings when the first mapping is triggered.  Remove the "nore" part of your map command and it will do what you expected:

```
imap ;p <p><Enter><Tab>INDENTED<Enter><S-Tab></p>
```

See: `:help nore`

Comment: thank you for the clarification. I had it in my mind that `nore` just prohibits overwriting of that same mapping. Obviously it makes much more sense the way it actually is.